# LiveEngage - LivePerson chat TAG shows nothing

Tags: javascript, html, .net, tags, liveperson

I followed the instructions on LiveEngage and inserted tag on my website but nothing changed. I don't see the chat window. There is no information on this topic anywhere. Maybe someone who is using LiveEngage - LivePerson chat and had same problem. Or anyone who is using it can help me to set it up.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? network issues? there is usually some configuration that needs to be done and the errors will give us a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to name my own tags, the tags didn't work. When I kept the default id (i.e. "LP_DIV_1467709781528"), the tags worked. Maybe the tag id needs to have "LP_DIV_..." in front of it. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert your LiveEngage Tag in the body?